# sorting and load balancing

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I read about parallel quicksort ( but no load balancing ).
who can give good algorithm for using on 2, 4, 8 cores?

Comment: What do you mean "load balancing"? Is this running on one machine, single process on 2, 4 or 8 cores - or two (or more) machines with 2, 4, 8 cores each?

Comment: yeah, single processor with 2, 4 or 8 cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Intel multicore CPUs, there's [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.140.8757&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This will give insight http://sortbenchmark.org/

Answer (score 0):

Algorithms doesnt depend on hardware.

You can implement your program to use multiple core cpus, ie: multi threading, however, quick sort is quick sort. the algorithms (idea) is same.

What you can do is, for a dual core CPU, once you divide the input to two, you can assign each partition to one core and continue in the same way. at the end you can merge the results. This is becoming like a merge sort though, except that you use a pivot.

Comment: :) yes, but when i will merge 2 sequences i will use only 1 core. If we suppose that we have 2 core, second core will do nothing. is it normal? If we have 4 cores... 8.... ?

Comment: you are not a programmer. i can tell that. and i m too lazy to write anything further than this.,